# How to use Grails JSON view without defining internal templates?

Tags: json, grails, grails3, grails3.2.0, json-view

I've a domain class:

```
class Business {
    String name
    String description
}
```

I have the following JSON templates :

`index.gson`: to generate the JSON for the list of objects

`_business.gson`: to generate JSON for Business object

**`index.gson`**

```
import server.Business
model {
    Iterable businessList
}
json {
    result tmpl.business(businessList ?: [])
}
```

**`_business.gson`**

```
model {
        Business business
}
json {
    id business.id
    name business.name
}
```

**HOW can I generate JSON for Business object without using _business.gson template?**

I want to go for a approach where I just have the index.gson and manually render the internal object.

```
import server.Business
model {
    Iterable businessList
}

json {
    **WHAT SHOULD I ADD HERE?**
}

json(businessList.toList()) {
    **I also noticed that I can use this syntax, BUT WHAT SHOULD I ADD HERE?**
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do whatever you want inside the `json` closure.

```
json(businessList.toList()) { Business business ->
    id business.id
    name business.name
    description business.description
}
```